# Why open Call Hierarchy on a method is not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE 3.6 version .

Inside my code i have a method as

```
public APIRes execute(APIReq request) throws Exception {
// Some code 
}
```

Could you please tell me , when i did open  Call Hierarchy , nothing is shown .
Why is it so ??

Comment: Bug fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346785  In next PDT 3.3.1 it can be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is that there may be nothing calling that method - at least within the code that Eclipse knows about. Beyond that, we really can't say...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that Open Call Hierarchy was not searching the entire Workspace. 
Click on the small down arrow (in the Call Hierarchy view window on the right; it is the "View Menu" arrow -- a triangle pointing down) in Call Hierarchy view, set the Search Scope > Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Call Hierarchy or Class Referencing.

If your create a method and nobody calls it, what do you expect to see in the call hierarchy.
Your method is referencing the class in which the method is placed. This would be shown in the reference view.

Answer (score 0):

first clear the project and refresh it and select the method press right click open call hierarchy you will get the class where  method declaration is defined.